# Access multidimensional array keys with on-the-fly generated variables with php (need to avoid eval)

Tags: php, multidimensional-array, eval

I need to avoid eval() again. I want to access a multidimensional array like this:

```
$items = $xml2array[$explode_path[0]][$explode_path[1]];
```

The thing is that $explode_path[0] and $explode_path[1] are calculated through a for loop:

`for($i=0; $i<$count_explode; $i++) { }`

Right now the entire code looks like this:

```
function getValues($contents, $xml_path) {
    $explode_path = explode('->', $xml_path);
    $count_explode = count($explode_path);
    $xml2array = xml2array($contents);

    $correct_string = '$items = $xml2array';

    for($i=0; $i<$count_explode; $i++) {
        $correct_string .= '[$explode_path['.$i.']]';
    }

    $correct_string .= ';';
    eval($correct_string);
    return $items;
}

$contents = readfile_chunked($feed_url, true);
$items = getValues($contents, 'deals->deal'); # will get deals->deal from MySQL

foreach($items as $item) {
    echo $item['deal_title']['value'].' - '.$item['dealsite']['value'].'<br />';
}
```

I can't figure out how I can access the $xml2array array that way:

```
$items = $xml2array[$explode_path[0]][$explode_path[1]];
```

Any help would be highly appreciated!

Comment: "I need to avoid eval() again" -- thats a good start :-)

Comment: What is the output of `readfile_chunked`?

Comment: readfile_chunked() is a custom function like file_get_contents(). It downloads a large file into smaller chunks of bytes in order to avoid large memory consumption. When the file has finished downloading it returns the file contents.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about replacing your `getValues()` function with:

```
function getValues($contents, $xml_path) {
    $explode_path = explode('->', $xml_path);
    $count_explode = count($explode_path);
    $items = xml2array($contents);

    for($i=0; $i<$count_explode; $i++) {
        $items = $items[$explode_path[$i]];
    }

    return $items;
}
```

**Edit:** Cleaner version:

```
function getValues($contents, $xml_path) {
    $items = xml2array($contents);

    foreach(explode('->', $xml_path) as $k)
    {
        $items = $items[$k];
    }

    return $items;
}
```

Comment: Great, but wait a second, I'll get you an even cleaner version

Comment: OK, now that's way too awesome Thank you so much!